# Fix the navbar on scrolling

Tags: tailwind-css

```
return (
  <nav className=" bg-violet-900">
    <div >

   <div className="flex justify-between py-12 px-5"> 

         <h1 className="text-6xl text-white">AS</h1>
         <div className="   text-white text-2xl  lg:hidden">
<i onClick={click} className={navbar===false ? "fas fa-bars" :"fas fa-times"}></i>
</div >
</div>
 
 

<div className="">
<ul className={navbar===true  ?" bg-violet-900 text-right text-white  z-10 flex flex-col  " :"hidden"}>  
  <Link className="  px-8 py-3" to='/'> Home</Link>
  <Link  className="px-8 py-3"to='/projects'>Projects</Link>
  <Link className=" px-8 py-3"to='/about'>Resume</Link>
  <Link className=" px-8 py-3"to='/about'>About</Link>

  </ul> 
  </div>
 

  </div>
 </nav>
```

//this is my navbar for mobile responsiveness on scrolling the navbar doesn't   fix on top of screen any help
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`<nav className="sticky top-0 bg-violet-900">`

Might just do the job.

Comment: Might need to include `top-0` in there as well.

`<nav className="sticky top-0 flex bg-violet-900">`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works. Earlier I tried using the sticky but it didn't work.I don't know why that happened .Thanks for helping me out